# Retrain facenet neural network

Tags: python, pytorch

I want to use the pretained MTCNN model to train in a subset of images, and keep the layers that are important to get the features of the images. Also, I want to use another loss function.

```
import torch
from facenet_pytorch import InceptionResnetV1, MTCNN
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader
from torchvision import datasets
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import os

workers = 0 if os.name == 'nt' else 4
device = torch.device('cuda:0' if torch.cuda.is_available() else 'cpu')
print('Running on device: {}'.format(device))

mtcnn = MTCNN(
    image_size=160, margin=0, min_face_size=20,
    thresholds=[0.6, 0.7, 0.7], factor=0.709, post_process=True,
    device=device
)
```

The problem is that I don't know how to face the problem of "freezing" some layers of the neural network that I don't want to tune and tune only the last layers. Also, how to apply the new criterion to this pretrained network.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can first print out or visualize the MTCNN `model`, so you will know the `name (key)` of the layer you want to freeze. Assuming the name of the layer is `feature_layer`, you can then simple do:

```
for name, param in model.named_parameters():
    if not 'feature_layer' in name:
        param.requires_grad = False
```

So it will freeze every other layers except the last layer `feature_layer`.
Then your other parameters will follow suit:

```
optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(params, lr=1e-3)
lr_scheduler = torch.optim.lr_scheduler.StepLR(optimizer, step_size=10, gamma=0.1)
```

Now, to change the criterion, you change it here to one of the default ones, or use a custom one:

```
loss_fn = torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
```

Answer (score 0):

One idea is to stop gradient calculation of the mtcnn model ...

```
for param in mtcnn.parameters():
    param.requires_grad = False
```

You can then replace the final layer (or as many you need) of mtcnn with ones that you create ...

```
mtcnn.fc = nn.Linear(num_in_features, my_num_out_features)
```

Then train as usual, only fc layer will be trained.